# Как работает kdf

Tags: алгоритм, безопасность, криптография, хеширование

Объясните, пожалуйста, как при одинаковом входящем пароле на выходе мы получаем разные ключи?

Понимаю основные криптопримитивы симметричное/ассиметричное шифрование, блочное/поточное, хэширование, mac/hmac, но не kdf :(

Например bcrypt. Как он это делает? Ладно, как делает можно понять, просто с солью мешаем и разные значения получаем, но как он потом валидирует что этот пароль валидный под этот ключ, если соль рандомная была?

Comment: По моему дело в том что соль известна, и она хранится вместе с зашифрованными данными.

Comment: @coder675 но ведь тогда смысл соли пропадает

Comment: Не пропадает.  Смысл соли в том, что по двум ключам ты не сможешь сказать, что они из одного пароля сделаны.

Comment: @alexey Это касалось предыдущего коментария. Соль - бессмысленна, если она хранится в хеше. Собственно в этом и вопрос, если соль разная каждый раз и неизвестна, то как мы можем проверить match пароля?

Comment: Соль (практически) всегда хранится вместе с хешом и это не бессмысленно.  Например http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-hash.php

Comment: Все, одновременно из нескольких источников ответ пришел) Всем спасибо, я выкупил)) Еще помогла ссылка https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331370/how-can-i-extract-the-salt-out-of-bcrypt-hash-passwords-in-php )) Проблема была в том, что я не знал, что соль в самом хеше и хранится

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Соль одновременно защищает от нескольких видов атак:

- Атака со словарем. Если злоумышленник сгенерировал несколько миллиардов паролей и хешей, он за линейное время может проверить, есть ли в словаре конкретный хеш, и какой пароль стоит под ним. Когда есть соль, такая таблица бесполезна, или нужно генерировать для каждой возможной соли свою таблицу (что при правильной длине соли бесполезное занятие).
- Радужные таблицы. Более продвинутая версия словаря, которая занимает меньше памяти.
- Защищает слабые пароли. Даже если сотни юзеров поставили пароль "qwerty", злоумышленник видит в базе разные хеши, и для взлома паролей ему нужно работать с каждым пользователем отдельно.

Как видно, даже если соль известна злоумышленнику, это создает очень серьезные неудобства.